# Delete record from a dynamically created form using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I want to delete the records that are dynamically created but the code is not working..Please have a look

script.js

```
$(function() {

            $('#studentRecord').on('click', 'button.delete', function() {

            var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

            var $id = parseInt( $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1] );


            if ( confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record") ) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ab_batch/practice/db/action.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        action: 'ajaxDelRecord',
                        id: JSON.stringify(id)
                    },

                    success: function() {},


                    error: function() {}

                });

            }


        });


    });
```

action.php

```
$action = ( isset($_REQUEST['action']) && !empty($_REQUEST['action']) ) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : null;
switch ($action) {
case 'ajaxDelRecord':

        if ( isset($_POST['id']) ) {
            $id = json_decode($_POST['id']);
        }

        $id = json_decode($_POST['id']);
        print ( $student->delRecord($id) ) ? 'true' : 'false' ;

        break;

}
```

There is another file db.php that contains all the APIs for delete, add and update

Comment: `JSON.stringify(id)` should be `JSON.stringify($id)` as you are declaring your `id` as `$id` , you don't really need : `JSON.stringify` as you are just sending an integer to the server.

Comment: @ArshSingh thanks alot its working but the page needs to be reloaded to view the result...as i am using ajax shouldn't the result reflect as soon as I hit the delete button?

Comment: You should delete the div after the server answer your ajax request. it is not going to reflect the change until you don't say to javascript to delete the specific html element that you recently deleted by sending the request to the server

Comment: let me show u in answer and post this whole thing as answer

Comment: Okay..will try...thanks

Comment: okay sure....that would be very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.stringify(id) should be JSON.stringify($id) as you are declaring your id as $id , you don't really need : JSON.stringify as you are just sending an integer to the server.

and for deleting the line which you just removed from database , you can just replace your javascript code with following:

```
$(function() {

            $('#studentRecord').on('click', 'button.delete', function() {

            var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

            var $id = parseInt( $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1] );


            if ( confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record") ) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/ab_batch/practice/db/action.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        action: 'ajaxDelRecord',
                        id: JSON.stringify($id)
                    },

                    success: function() {},

                      $tr.remove(); // removing the current deleted record from html.
                    error: function() {}

                });

            }


        });


    });
```

i did add `$tr.remove();` inside a success callback , as you have already declared the parent element of the deleted record , so you just need to use : `$tr.remove();` to delete the tr.

Comment: Its working....but if i delete the top most record having serial no 1 the page doesn't automatically replaces the next record with serial no 1...instead the second record has a serial no 2 and only after refreshing its shows serial no 1...is there a way??? Hope i am not bothering you too much

Comment: Why not just auto refresh the page after record is deleted so you see immediate result , i mean : add `location.reload();` after `$tr.remove();` ... if it helped you , please consider accepting as answer. thanks.